# Viewpager with auto scroll android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, autoscroll

I'm using viewpager library to implement image slider but don't know how to implement it to auto scroll. here is my code.

**ViewPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements IconPagerAdapter{

private int[] Images = new int[] { R.drawable.viewpager, R.drawable.viewpager,
        R.drawable.viewpager, R.drawable.viewpager,R.drawable.viewpager, R.drawable.viewpager

};

protected static final int[] ICONS = new int[] { R.drawable.logo,
        R.drawable.logo, R.drawable.logo, R.drawable.logo,R.drawable.logo, R.drawable.logo };

private int mCount = Images.length;

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return new SliderFragment(Images[position]);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mCount;
}

public int getIconResId(int index) {
    return ICONS[index % ICONS.length];
}

public void setCount(int count) {
    if (count > 0 && count <= 10) {
        mCount = count;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}

**SliderFragment.java**

```
public class SliderFragment extends SherlockFragment {

int imageResourceId;

public SliderFragment(int i) {
    imageResourceId = i;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ImageView image = new ImageView(getActivity());
    image.setImageResource(imageResourceId);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    layout.addView(image);

    return layout;
}
```

}

**MainActivity.java**

```
mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    vPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pIndicator = (PageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    vPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    pIndicator.setViewPager(vPager);
    ((CirclePageIndicator) pIndicator).setSnap(true);
```

Please guide me how can i implement it with auto scroll so that images are scrolling automatically after the predefined time.

Comment: Zeeshan. Came to know about the answer?

Comment: hi can any one help me for listview with card flip rotation of item.when i click any of the item flip all listitems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it using the timer thread. After specific time i change the view pager image which become the auto scroll.

Answer (score 2):

```
page=0;

timer=new TimerTask() {
            @Override
    enter code here
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(page % 4); // 4= no. of page in viewpager

                        page++;
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        Timer time=new Timer();
        time.schedule(timer, 0, 3000); //3000 millisecond for replace the viewpager page
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience.